# Where is the nonce incremented in Bitcoin source code?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, nonce

Where is the nonce incremented in Bitcoin source code?
I found where the extra nonce is incremented, but not the regular nonce?

Answer (score 1):

Line 132 in src/mining.cpp in the generateBlocks method.

```
while (nMaxTries > 0 && pblock->nNonce < nInnerLoopCount && !CheckProofOfWork(pblock->GetHash(), pblock->nBits, Params().GetConsensus())) {
    ++pblock->nNonce;
    --nMaxTries;
}
```

**Update**: Given @MeshCollider's answer I guess this is now only relevant on the regtest network.

Comment: Oh yes, there is still a miner for regtest, forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

The internal miner was removed from Bitcoin Core in version 0.13.0, in this PR:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7507

It used to be incremented in ScanHash(), but as of the removal, there is nowhere which increments the nonce, that would be done by mining software.